# I cannot get my user defined checked exception to work properly

Tags: java

I am required to create a user defined checked exception.  Unfortunately when I try to throw it I get the error: unreported exception InsufficientFunds; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

I have identified the exception in the method signature, and then thrown it within the method where I want it to happen.  However, I still cannot understand the mistake I am making.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Code examples:
main()

```
if (e.getSource() == deposit) {
    accountType.deposit(money);
} else if (e.getSource() == withdraw) {
    if (money % 20 == 0) {
        accountType.withdraw(money);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry must be in $20 increments.");
    }
}
```

In this example, I am receiving the unreported exception error at "accountType.deposit(money);" which runs the following method:

```
public void withdraw(Double money) throws InsufficientFunds {
    if (count >= 4) {
        this.money = (money + FEE);
    } else {
        this.money = money;
    }
    if (this.balance < this.money) {
        throw new InsufficientFunds("You don't have enough money to do that!");
    } else {
        this.balance -= this.money;
        count++;    
    }
}
```

Here is my user defined exception class

```
public class InsufficientFunds extends Exception {

    public InsufficientFunds(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Anyone that can put a set of eyes on this and provide me with some knowledge would be greatly appreciated.  I am sure I have overlooked something simply.

Thank you,
Bryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are throwing a custom exception called `InsufficientFunds` in your `withdraw()` method, but you never *catch* that exception in the calling method.  So one way to make the error go away is to place the call to `withdraw()` inside a `try-catch` block:

```
if (e.getSource() == deposit) {
    accountType.deposit(money);
} else if (e.getSource() == withdraw) {
    if (money % 20 == 0) {
        try {
            accountType.withdraw(money);
        }
        catch (InsufficientFunds ife) {
            System.out.println("No funds to withdraw.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some other error occurred.");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry must be in $20 increments.");
    }
}
```

If you look closely, you will see that I first catch an `InsufficientFunds` exception, followed by a general `Exception`.  This is the pattern you usually want to follow, namely catching specific exceptions followed by more general ones, and finally catching `Exception` to make certain that you handle every use case which might go wrong.

The alternative to this would be to have the method which calls `withdraw()` to *also* throw an exception, i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InsufficientFunds {
    if (e.getSource() == deposit) {
        accountType.deposit(money);
    } else if (e.getSource() == withdraw) {
        if (money % 20 == 0) {
            accountType.withdraw(money);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry must be in $20 increments.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  This was tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing the custom exception, but it is never caught in `withdraw()`. Java uses a Catch or Declare Rule, meaning that an exception must either be caught in a `catch` block or declared in the method heading with the `throws` keyword.

See [this reference](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/javatutorial/java/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) for additional details.